# Introducing noise to a binary class

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset that I'm running classification on and the class itself is binary (0, 1). Essentially I want to introduce some noise to the class column, that is, randomly invert 5% of the classes. I.e. if I had 1000 rows of data I would want to invert the class of 50 of these.

My variables are like

```
data = read_csv(...)
x = dataset.drop("class", axis=1)
y = dataset["class"]
```

And I want to introduce the noise to `y` where each row in y is either 0 or 1

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can do this in a somewhat long one line with `np.where`. At the moment, I can't seem to remember it. But, I have done a version of this in the past and it's worked just fine. All you're doing is changing one value to something outside of your choices, like a placeholder, changing the other, and changing the placeholder to your desired output. Since you're using binary data (0, 1), we'll just introduce the number two, temporarily. This gives us something to swap around.

```py
sample_indexes = df.sample(.05).index.values

df.loc[(sample_indexes) & (df['my_column'] == 1), 'my_column] = 2
df.loc[(sample_indexes) & (df['my_column'] == 0), 'my_column] = 1
df.loc[(sample_indexes) & (df['my_column'] == 2), 'my_column] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `data` is your binary array. Draw a random mask from a binomial distribution with the probability of 1 being 5%:

```
mask = np.random.binomial(1, 0.05, data.shape[0]).astype(bool)
```

Invert the mask to invert the values:

```
data[mask] = 1 - data[mask]
```